# Finding the best binary tree with a general property

Tags: co.combinatorics, binary-tree

Let $N=\{1,\dots,n\}$. Let $M$ be the set of all binary trees $B$ formed from all elements of $N$ (i.e of size $n$). Let $P$ be a numeric property defined for all $B\in M$. Let $O\in M$ be the optimal $B$ that minimizes $P$.

Example: Let $P$ be the sum of the heights of all nodes of $B$. This measures the "balancing" of $B$, and for $n=2^m-1$ $O$ is even unique.

Task: Given $P$, find (some - ties are OK) $O$.

Attempt 1: Stupid but surefire. Generate all permutations $\Pi$ of $N$. Generate the canonic tree (start empty, insert the elements of $\Pi$ in their order). Compute $P$, pick best $O$.

Attempt 2: If it is possible to derive a simple algorithm that takes a Hamilton walk through the "rotahedron" $G$ of $M$ ($B$ and $B'$ are connected in $G$ if a left rotation move turns $B$ into $B'$) this would at least reduce the load from $n!$ to Catalan($n$). *My question*: Is such an algorithm known?

Note: If $P$ is "very local" such that $G$, turned to a directed graph by pointing the arrow to the smaller $P$, is a DAG, this would speed up things enormously (start anywhere, follow the arrows), but even then, you could end up in a local minimum. ("My" $P$, BTW, would be again the sum of the heights, but dropping the first $k$ elements of $\Pi$.)

Comment: Imagine if $P=0$ for exactly one tree and $P=1$  for all other trees.  How are you going to know without looking at all trees? To do better you need $P$ to have some structure .

Comment: @BrendanMcKay: Indeed. In the worst case I must look at all trees. ("My" $P$ has *some* structure but using it is a much harder problem than giving at least a "Catalan" algorithm actually looking at all trees, and I would already be content with that.)

Comment: What does it mean to "form a binary tree from all elements of $N$"? Are the elements labelling all vertices or just the leaves? Does the reference to the canonical tree in attempt 1 imply that $M$ should actually only contain balanced binary trees? Does the reference to the rotahedron in attempt 2 imply that $M$ should actually only contain trees with the leaves in one given order (when read in pre-, in-, or post-order traversal)?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'm confident that Hauke intends to construct a binary search tree by processing the integers as keys in the order they appear in the permutation.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay, if so then there's a polynomial-time solution for any cost function $P$ which depends only on the costs of the two subtrees and the elements in the two subtrees, but I'm still not clear then whether the $\Pi$ of "my" $P$ is fixed or whether it relates to the $\Pi$ of attempt 1.

Comment: @PeterTaylor $P$ depends only on the tree structure, since the labels on the nodes after using a permutation to generate the tree depend only on the tree structure.  It is in-order. You are right that functions that can be defined recursively will provide much faster optimisation algorithms than looking at every tree, but without more information about what type of $P$ Hauke is interested in not much more can be said.

Comment: Purpose of "my" $P$: Do a "canonical" tree from $\Pi$, query all keys once in the order of $\Pi$, for a queried key $k$ let $\Pi'$ the search path of $k$, permute $\Pi'$ (by tree rotations) such that the added heights of all elements of $\Pi$, *except* those already queried, are minimal. Intuitively, this should yield a "good" dynamic tree algorithm.

Comment: To put in in relation: The "Greedy Future" algorithm (the best online?!) tries to pull down only the *next* query (queries if tied) to the root as far as possible. I want to pull down the sum of the costs of all queries, so to say.

Comment: Final comment: "My" $P$ simply works with the Hu-Tucker algorithm, and my proposed dynamic tree (only for querying all keys $k$ of a permutation once!) can be described as: If key $k$ is found on search path $p$, place on $p$ as weights $w$ the number of yet unqueried keys. Rotate $p$ such that the $w$ are in the Hu-Tucker optimum. (Details for ties still need research :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to generate the binary trees systematically. An older example is in [this paper](https://watermark.silverchair.com/290171.pdf%5DADCCAqcGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMrKjgZkHACgY74gsDAgEQgIICeMZ44ylFTEpgx8fPGdZC0E8nZO4Pmd0nc0uOXM3dRDI03jqH5OdyxRr6xUxItzDL8H88_Dxae1YoAzHc4UynsczKNba1D3k7jk7VGuk293X-4zKk0gYt8RBXF0zo8kDqORhgYlaT5jeROsI0p1RAwxgoSclskVQIxrWQfleFRGbOP5P61HpxD0KzztfGbFks-nn92Ws2xB73dNi8N-gGyJDvHqyYJmTxqLRQixJvvuHnLl6imFlCmHvR5se5ozkoRi7rsrfTKUOdB7FuP1K6Y__8i6KRCucJ1WbFNXm22JsYr2OHH074uyXnoswSF9SG1Pd6Ffsh4VFIQaLsQpHp-FqaQ4lWRaF_ZEyLta74b-C_CTEynpvYfv1C16mU_lOc03IFLcP5UvzdAy65rPihALMDVtnhspuYRMNW2oKbpCNP-sGeQb0TZkpJgfoziOOwoV9ZcGqM-hoI4an0dBTJhFOKVFjwgfg8DpSIJYqu1yGCvvxeKSo4I-Ouiw7r1ZlKMdGZ6XUk8oAN5scfH_Ky2dEC0pG4PhUJzMxjmYSGe6mSR_YhNVc691DMVb_G9akVvLBIgiM1VULPeizNsIxp6yhv9vwzDgyGV3kK2iNXDO0NBZUs_FjY1p-QD35SXPPDoR8tPcT4_YmJdCZUOzUsdkyczmCO6fAVDOI3QAPKKBXzJQLFDXPCN8grdaekEFXScAYIU57-_It_sQdEk3AylucTi6jaf1_NT1_-c_H6UYgcxIJcew9fB5iXge2N_D6L0YIMIhAnGjxetn57nxEWFvuo1KgbYU-TGTOD0Hl8KffPMywYJaJil4Bf6eP6lwAri5H_tEjD5haA).

Another one, perhaps more efficient for your purposes, is [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/0196-6774(90)90030-I).

Comment: Ha, now that I know which phrases to search, I see even GeeksForGeeks has programs. :-) THX for the paper, I prefer to write a proggie myself and this surely will be helpful.